# How to get index number of clicked element from MouseEvent object

Tags: javascript, dom, mouseevent, queryselector

I am trying to get the index of the clicked element from the `MouseEvent` object. When I go console click event objects "path" property and hover to first array item it marks actually clicked element.

I wonder how come engine knows which was clicked? Because event.path[0] selector doesn't contain index number of clicked element.

```
<div id="container">
    <div>abc</div>
    <div>abc</div>
    <div>abc</div>
    <div>abc</div>
    <div>abc</div>
    <div>abc</div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9n3f7mcr/

Comment: I think you may be looking for the `target` attribute of the `event` object

Comment: event.target doesnt contain index number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) on the children of the parent of `event.target`, if all the elements you may want the index of have the same parent.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var target = e.target;
  var parent = target.parentNode;
  var index = [].indexOf.call(parent.children, target);
  console.log("index:", index);
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div>1z</div>
<div>2z</div>
<div>3z</div>
<div>4z</div>
<div>5z</div>
<div>6z</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tested your code on actual DOM it turns out fails to return correct index, try: https://jsfiddle.net/vh9dmckz/3/   clicking first input retruns 1 as index

Comment: @Tek That's completely different markup than your example in the question.

Comment: @Tek Those `input`s are not all under the same parent.

Comment: but it should work all valid DOM structure not only my given example

Comment: @Tek Different DOM structures require different strategies; you should have specified exactly what your HTML looked like.

Comment: @Tek If you want it to work for the inputs, link, and button on your JSFiddle, you can try this: https://jsfiddle.net/prodakz0/

Comment: @Tek No problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go about this depending on how you want to use the index of each child element. I think [using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) is generally a good approach:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div data-id="1">1z</div>
  <div data-id="2">2z</div>
  <div data-id="3">3z</div>
  <div data-id="4">4z</div>
  <div data-id="5">5z</div>
  <div data-id="6">6z</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
const container = document.getElementById("container");

function handleClick(evt) {
  const childNode = evt.target.closest("div");
  console.log(childNode.dataset.id);
}

container.addEventListener("click", handleClick, false);
```